# How can I combine these two printf statements in C?

Tags: c, printf

I'm trying to print "Hello the number 5 is correct!" in C.

The way I'm doing it now is with two printf statements:

```
printf("Hello the number %d", number);
printf(" is correct!\n");
```

How can I do this in one statement like in Java:

```
System.out.println("Hello the number "+number+" is correct!");
```

I've tried doing it this way in C:

```
printf("Hello the number %d", number, " is correct!");
```

but the "is correct!" doesn't show up.

is there a way to do this in one statement?
I'm sorry I'm very new to C.

Comment: The [`printf` manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) is your friend. Always first read the man-pages (or similar documentation of functions you use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can embed the format specifier into the middle of the string like so:

```
printf("Hello the number %d is correct!\n", number);
```

Alternatively, you can use another format specifier for the rest of the string:

```
printf("Hello the number %d%s\n", number, " is correct!");
```

Answer (score 1):

The `printf` function expects the format of your string, followed by the arguments referenced by the format.

```
printf("Hello the number %d is correct!\n", number);
```

In your case `printf("Hello the number %d", number, " is correct!")` will be understood as "`Hello the number %d`" as the format of your string with `number` and " `is correct!`" as arguments and as you have only one argument referenced in your format, " `is correct!`" doesn't appear in the resulting string, this is the reason why "`is correct!`" doesn't show up.

Comment: C does not support _methods_. And even in a OOPL `printf` was just a function.

Answer (score 0):

Your try is not working because you have 1 appender (%d) but 2 parameters (**number** and  **" is correct!"**)

try instead...

```
int main(void) {
     int number =0;
   printf("Hello the number %d   is correct!", number);
    return 0;
}
```